# error when custom class extends FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I create a custom class and it extends `FloatingActionButton`

```
public class customFAB extends FloatingActionButton
{
    public customFAB(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

I call this class from MainActivity

```
customFAB cFab = new customFAB(getApplicationContext);
```

But I get this error

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

my `style.xml` is

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

theme is `Theme.AppCompat`. so what is the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your main activity extending AppCompat?

Comment: @JuliánMartínez no, MainActivty extends AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Application`'s `Context` will not have a theme on it, despite the fact that you may set your app's default theme by using the `theme` attribute on the `<application>` element in your manifest. You need to use your `Activity`'s `Context` when instantiating `View`s like that.

For example:

```
customFAB cFab = new customFAB(MainActivity.this);
```